# Why isn't Visual Studio 2010 recognizing CUDA functions?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cuda

I just got the CUDA drivers and the CUDA toolkit 4.2 installed onto my machine with all of the standard options. I have a CUDA capable NVIDIA GPU.

For some reason, the Visual Studio compiler, despite having the CUDA files located in the Program Files/MSBuild/Microsoft.cpp/v4.0/BuildCustomizations, will not compile a simple kernel function:

```
__global__ void kernel(void){

    //I do nothing :(

}
```

It registers a type specifier error on the `__global__`.

Is there something more that I have to do?

Also, I have been having some trouble (IDE's and I are never compatible) with Visual Studio and its want to create a ton of files. I added all of the source and header files by "Add" and selecting "Existing File," so I believe that my source files are not with Visual Studio's plethora of files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to include some header files?

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://weknowmemes.com/2012/03/people-say-nothings-impossible-but-i-do-nothing-everyday/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable CUDA build customizations and did you name your CUDA file with a ".cu" extension? To get to the build customizations in Visual Studio 2010, right click the CUDA project in the Solution Explorer and select Build Customizations.

Comment: Thanks. That got the .cu files working, but not the c files. Can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886104/how-do-i-set-up-my-code-vs10-to-recognize-cuda-function-calls-within-c-files as well?