# How do I set up my code/VS10 to recognize CUDA function calls within .c files?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, build, compiler-errors, cuda

Basically, I have the compiler compiling my .cu files and I have (I think) full operation within those .cu files, but when I try to call them (`kernel<<<1,1>>>(void)`), the compiler registers syntax errors due to the CUDA syntax. Also, calls like cudaMalloc fail within c files.

Here are three really short files, so I can tell you where it is erroring.

```
//kernel.cu    
#include "kernel.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ int kernel(void){     
    return 5;
}
```

and

```
//kernel.h
#ifndef _KERNEL_h_
#define _KERNEL_h_

extern "C" int kernel(void);

#endif
```

and

```
//main.c
#include "kernel.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main() {
   int* device_a;

   cudaMalloc( (void**)&device_a, sizeof(int) );

   kernel<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

I got the header file from some of the SDK examples. Also, I have my build configuration set with CUDA 4.2, hence why the .cu file compiles. If I made any incidental syntax errors, it is because I simplified it for posting, not that it is actually in the source, although please mention it just in case.

kernel.cu compiles fine.

kernel.h has an error: "error C2059: syntax error : 'string'" on the "extern..." line. (Could this be because I took that from a c++ example?)

main.c has an error: "error C2065: 'kernel' : undeclared identifier"

and: "error C2059: syntax error : '<'"

but when I comment out the kernel call, so it is just cudaMalloc, I get: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cudaMalloc@8 referenced in function _main"

and: "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"

Is it something with Visual Studio 2010, or is it something I am not including? From the SDK examples, I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, other then they found a way, I think, to not use the triple bracket (CTRL+F doesn't find any). Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: after looking at some more examples, they do use the triple bracket syntax just fine.

EDIT: **For those using this as reference**, `__global__` functions can only return void. If you try to return anything else, as I did, you will receive compiler errors.

Comment: How you managed to successfully compile and run the kernel does not return void?

Comment: I didn't. That was another flaw that I found out later. It registers a really clear compiler error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put the functions that invoke CUDA kernel in **.cu** files.
2. Set up VS2010 to compile CU files with the CUDA compiler, not the built in one (use the CUDA rules files (Cuda.props, Cuda.xml, Cuda.targets) located within the CUDA SDK).
3. I recommend placing kernels in files with a different extension (e.g. **.curnel** files), so that they will not be compiled directly (only if called).
4. I recommend putting the declaration of the functions that invoke CUDA kernels in **.cuh** files.

Comment: Search results produce this guide (which I have not read, so I take no responsibility for its correctness): http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/08/getting-cuda-3-1-working-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: I have the build configuration set to compile the .cu files with the CUDA compiler, I think. I put a function within the .cu file that calls the kernel, but that function still has syntax errors on the brackets. It also seems to me the the .cu and the .c files have no knowledge of each other, because even when the .cu file compiles, the main function cannot call plain c functions within.

Comment: The .cu and .c files should only see .cuh and .h files that they reference in the includes section. The linker connects them. Add #ifdef CUDACC (can't remember the exact syntax - check SDK) above each .cu file to make sure the compile definitions are correct.

Comment: @EricThoma: Did you remember to create a header file for the functions in the .cu file and #include it in your .c file?

Comment: @EricThoma: Re. the syntax errors, don't worry about them as long as the file compiles. VC++ is checking the file for syntax errors as if it was a .c file. You can leave it as is, but if you want to fix it: http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/

Comment: @DannyVarod I got CUDA working in the C files now, and the angle bracket syntax is working. The only problem is that my C function call(), which is in the cu file and calls the kernel, isn't able to be called from main. I have the prototype for call in kernel.h, which is included in main. The error is: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol call referenced in function main." Basically, main sees the prototype but doesn't see the actual function, I believe. Any advice? Thanks a ton, you've been a huge help.

Comment: @EricThoma: Put the include inside the curly brackets of `extern "C" {}`.

Comment: @Roger Dahl Wow, thanks a ton. You have no idea how much frustration that saved me. I wish you got some stackoverflow points for this!

Comment: @EricThoma: SO points are just "thank you's" in numeric form. Your written one is much appreciated. Have fun with your CUDA project. :)